# Using the windowing Method

Tags: continuous-signals, window-functions

I'm trying to write a C program that can get the PSD of an recorded audio file, I'm using for the `fftw3` library. I wrote a program that calculate the PSD so far only for sinus function, but the result is correct, my problem is that I have some trouble to use the windowing method on my data.

Let's say that the audio file has following properties :

```
fs = 44100;
length = 10sec;
```

So I got `441000`samples, and I want to use windows, doesn't matter which one, with the size of 512, 25% overlapping, and shift my windows for the data. How could I know which value of the result is representing which frequency?

In Matlab it was easy here what I've done for example  :

```
  [x,fs] = audioread('fileName.wav');
  [xPSD,f] = pwelch(x,hanning(8192),4096,8192*4 ,fs);
```

Thanks for any help or explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$-th FFT bin will contain the complex amplitude for frequency $\frac{k}{512} \times 44100$.

Comment: so if I get a 1028 windows the bin that I get a everytime k/1028 * fs  ?

Comment: Yes. The denominator is the window size.

Comment: for 5104 samples and a windows size of 1025 I'll use 5 times the windows for  how can I order the result  the frequency axis ??

Comment: The k-th FFT bin will correspond to frequency k/1025 x 44100

Comment: pwelch vector sums the magnitudes of the results of all the multiple FFTs.  Then you only have a single result vector to plot.